# Is there a way to inject a SCSS class into a React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, dart-sass

I've built a simple `Panel.tsx` component in React, using TypeScript:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { Label, LabelType } from 'components/basic';

import styles from './Panel.module.scss';

interface IPanel {
  title?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Panel = ({ title, children }: IPanel) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.main}>
      {title && <Label type={LabelType.Title} bold text={title} />}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Panel;
```

Here's the companion `Panel.module.scss` file:

```
.main {
  border: 2px solid $black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Now, if I want to inject a SCSS class into `Panel`, perhaps with a `color`, `background-color`, `font-size`, etc. is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite common to write components in such a way that they accept a `className` property (but which must be applied to the component root explicitly by the component author). E.g. all components from `material-ui` accept a classname (I'm not a big fan of material-ui but at least this aspect they got right).

You can either add it explicitly to your prop type

```
interface IPanel {
  title?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  className?: string;
}
```

...and use it in your component

```
import classnames from 'clsx'; // this is a popular package to combine classnames

const Panel = ({ title, children, className }: IPanel) => {
  return (
    <div className={classnames(styles.main, className)}>
      {title && <Label type={LabelType.Title} bold text={title} />}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

...or you can use one of the utility types from React. E.g. I often just allow all common HTML attributes plus children to be added as props (Yes, I know, my types are not overly precise)

```
import type { FunctionComponent, HTMLAttributes } from 'react';
export type CommonPropsFunctionComponent<TProps = {}> = FunctionComponent<
  TProps & HTMLAttributes<Element>
>;
```

```
import { CommonPropsFunctionComponent } from './types';

interface IPanel {
  title?: string;
}

const Panel: CommonPropsFunctionComponent<IPanel>  = ({ title, children, className }) => {
  return (
    <div className={classnames(styles.main, className)}>
      {title && <Label type={LabelType.Title} bold text={title} />}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

*Using the spread operator*

You might be tempted to use it here; but beware: you must be careful to not overwrite your own local classname accidently.
To illustrate this, in this example:

- local `tabIndex` can be overwritten
- local `className` list cannot be overwitten, only extended

```
const SomeComponent= ({ children, className, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <div tabIndex={0} {...rest} className={classnames(styles.root, className)}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'm very familiar with `cx(...)` and use it all the time.

I'm confused by a few things with what you wrote.  In which file does the `className` string passed via the `className` prop reside?  Is it in a global SCSS file?

Assuming this is the case, I suppose that would work.  What would be better would be to pass in a custom class, created-on-the-fly, and simply defined within as JSON string, such as: `{background-color: yellow; border-width: 5px; padding: 17px;}`

Comment: Usually the classname that is provided lives in another css-module file and would therefore during runtime look something like this `fsghs45shgdj526`. But that doesn't matter because in the calling code it is accessed like any other classname from a css-modlue via `style.mySpecialClass`